# How can I highlight .gitignore code for my README.md?

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, gitignore, readme, github-linguist

I wrote a README.md with parts of code and I want to highlight those parts with the right colors.

One of this code is a **.gitignore code**, that I would like to integrate to my **README.md**. But I can't have the good linguist highlight for this, which colorize in green my comments for example.

I have searched some languages detected by GFM but I am not satisfied by the results.

Can someone help me to find the good linguist ?

P.S. : I also want to question for a DockerFile, docker-compose in a REAMDE code highlight.

Thanks,
MushuLeDragon

Comment: Hi! I'm one of the maintainers of Linguist. I'm not sure I get your comment about green comments. Are you trying to find a syntax highlighter that colors comments in green or are you trying to avoid that? Could you post an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `.gitignore` there is no default linguist available; buy `sh` is the closest match, so you can use that.

Example: https://gist.github.com/binki/7e0710d92863276ba39091cb299725bd

And for `DockerFile`, `docker-compose` use `dockerfile` linguist. It's the default linguist.

````
```dockerfile
FROM golang:1.10-alpine3.8
ENV NAME demo
ENV SOURCEROOT /go/src/github.com/${NAME}
COPY . ${SOURCEROOT}
WORKDIR ${SOURCEROOT}
...
...
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your help !